# Highstock X-Axis: Categories in Place of Time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to use categories as x-values in Highstock? 
I don't need a time bar as x-axes, but something like numbered ratings.

This works in Highcharts, but i need the scrollbar functionality from Highstock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the developers of Highcharts/Highstock answered to my support request:
It's not possible to switch the navigator to something else than time intervals.

The only solution to my problem is a navigation with a master and detail chart like in this sample: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

Answer (score 4):

You can use highstock release, but use highcharts and scrollbar.

Take look at example:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis:{
        min:0,
        max:2,
        categories:['first','second','third','fourth']
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        enabled:false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: [1,3,4,6]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b826C/

Comment: This just shows me the standard browser scrollbar. What i need is the special feature to scroll in etc. from Highstock.

Comment: Ok... but there's no difference to Hihstock, now. So the question remains: How to get navigator displaying categories in place of time.

Comment: Well, you would like to scrollbar with navigator, so in my example it is, so what's more do you need?

Comment: There is no navigator in your sample... And navigator only seems to work with time/date. What i need is a navigation through integers (no. of rating).

Comment: You can try to link your own series which will be numeric, by series option in navigator http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get the functionality you want using Highstock and the following workaround:

The x-axis is a datetime and your series date ranges from datetime 0 to datetime x, here x is the number of categories you have.

Then when you format the xAxis label use:

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
    return categoryText[this.value];
   }
}
```

Similarly you can format, the text in the navigator,

categoryText is a local variable that contains the text names of your categories.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b826C/98/