# highstock x-axis is always time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've chose `highstock` instead of `highcharts` because I need scrolling functionality and I was noticed that `highstock` supports only Time labels, but I need to display String as well.

Is there any way to display String value in the x axis ticks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068028/highstock-x-axis-categories-in-place-of-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the formatter for labels on the xAxis to get what you want. See this jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/w7kyH/

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return 'my string'; 
        }
    }
},
```