# Highcharts - Cannot set x-axes categories in column charts with negative values

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Hi I have a column chart with negative values which is showing wrong x-axes categories value. I'm sending a pre-build JSON array from the server , but no matter what i can't get the x-axes categories to show the right values.

Here is the code :

```
     var chart_data = JSON.parse(data).avg_range;


                        console.log(chart_data.x_axes);

                        var safety_chart_average = {
                            chart: {
                                type: 'column',
                                renderTo: pattern + '-safety-mini-chart-section',
                                spacingRight: 20,
                                spacingLeft: 20,
                            },
                            rangeSelector: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            navigator: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            scrollbar: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            credits: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: "Avg Changes",
                                marginBottom: -10
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: chart_data.x_axes
                            },
                            series: chart_data.prices


 };
```

This is what i'm getting

[image]

The x-axes is showing wrong values, as you can see from the picture above.

But `console.log(chart_data.x_axes)` gives 
`["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3"]` which should be the correct x-axes label.

Please let me know how can i fix this x-axes label error.

Comment: How are you starting your `safety_chart_average` chart?

Comment: Like this  `var chart2 = new Highcharts.StockChart(safety_chart_average);`

Comment: Why are you using a StockChart? Is there any functionality you need in StockChart? If you use a regular chart this seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes i'm using stock chart for all the charts, because i need the OHLC, candlesticks charts , you know

Comment: I linked a possible solution in my answer, but I don't think you will be able to use a StockChart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending in `options` to a `StockChart`. If you look in [the API for `xAxis` on `StockChart`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis) you see that it has no `categories`.

If you are not using any Highstock functionality I would switch to a regular Highcharts-chart, using `new Highcharts.Chart` instead.

If you must use Highstock you will have to look into other alternatives, as the xAxis uses time intervals. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15068264/2732991) may give you some hope, depending of how you are using Highstock in your implementation.

Comment: Yes you're right, it seems that StockChart doesn't support x-axes categories. But just plain Chart met the needs for now. Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Highstock is containing all of Highcharts options. All you need is to change constructor. So in steps:

- include Highstock: `<script scr="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>`
- when you need Highstock, call: `new Highcharts.StockChart(options)`
- when you need Highcharts, call: `new Highcharts.Chart(options)`

Comment: Thanks. Yes i've used `new Highcharts.Chart(options)` to initialize it and x-axes categories.