# Highstock set xAxis values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I Used Hightcharts before. This was my code:

```
function drawLine(data, title, selector, name) {
    $(selector).highcharts({
        title: {
            text: title,
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: data.map(function(i) { return new Date(parseInt(i.Index.substr(6))).toDateString(); })
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Count '
            },
            plotLines: [
                {
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }
            ]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: name,
                data: data.map(function(i) { return i.Value; })
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

How can i do the same with Highstock?
Problem in:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: data.map(function(i) { return new Date(parseInt(i.Index.substr(6))).toDateString(); })
}
```

Highstock does not contain "categories".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068028/highstock-x-axis-categories-in-place-of-time

Comment: Highcharts and Highstock have a built in datetime axis type. If you are using datetime data, you should set your axis up accordingly, and skip the categories.